# How to Enable or Disable button in a column based on other column's value in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I'm working on an app in Oracle Apex. I have an Interactive Report based on the following query.

```
SELECT NAME, DATE, '' LINK_TO_PAGE
FROM APPLICATIONS
```

From the above query we can see that I have 2 columns(Name, Date) from the table Applications and an empty column(Link_to_page).

For the empty column Link_to_page I have set the attributes

- Type : Link
- Target : Page 2
- Link Text : Apply
- Link Attributes : class="t-Button t-Button--simple t-Button--hot t-Button--stretch"

What I want to do is disable the button in the Link_to_page column if the sysdate is greater than the date in the Date column.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to do it directly in query, e.g.

```
select name, 
       date, 
       case when sysdate > date then null
            else '<span class="t-Icon fa fa-box-arrow-out-ne"></span>'
       end link
from applications
```

(Note that `date` is an invalid column name in Oracle; it is reserved for datatype).

`LINK` column's

- type = Link
- Link's

  - target = Page 2
  - link text = #LINK#
  - link attributes = class="t-Button t-Button--simple t-Button--hot t-Button--stretch"

and that's it ... `CASE` will make sure that button isn't even displayed (so it won't actually "disable" it, as you wanted). See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But is it possible to disable or not display the button without changing the query?

Comment: it is more efficient to do that in your sql, otherwise you will need javascript